# Положение MDI потомка относительно обрамляющей формы

Tags: c#, winforms

Существует ли возможность получить положение дочерней формы в координатах обрамляющей? Если да, подскажите пожалуйста как это сделать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пусть ваша MDI-форма называется `fmMDI`, тогда `fmMDI.Location.X` и `fmMDI.Location.Y` будут указывать положение верхнего левого угла MDI-формы относительно родительской.

Проверяется элементарно: на вашу MDI-форму положите 2 лейбла и у этой формы в обработчике события `LocationChanged` напишите:

```
    private void fmMDI_LocationChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label1.Text = "X = " + this.Location.X;
        label2.Text = "Y = " + this.Location.Y;
    }
```

Тогда если родительскую форму не разворачивать на весь экран и перемещать по экрану, то куда бы и как мы не перемещали родителя, перемещение дочерней MDI-формы все равно будет относительно координат родительской.